# Map and display multiple Array inside an object - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON file which is nested to create dropdown mega menu levels, I am not sure how to map and render multiple levels of arrays and object to create a tree like structure.

**Below is my JSON Structure:**

```
{
  "megamenu": [
    {
      "name": "level1.1",
      "link": "#"
    },
    {
      "name": "level1.2",
      "link": "#",
      "level1.2.1": {
        "A": [
          {
            "name": "A-one",
            "link": "#"
          }
        ],
        "B": [
          {
            "name": "B-one",
            "link": "#"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "level1.3",
      "link": "#",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "level1.3.1",
          "link": "#",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "level1.3.1.1",
              "link": "#"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "level1.3.1.2",
          "link": "#",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "level1.3.1.2",
              "link": "#"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**I am able to map first level like this:**

```
let menuArray = [];
let menu = this.props.menu.megamenu
console.log(menu);
for (let key in menu) {
    menuArray.push(menu[key]);
    return (
        <section>
            <ul>
                {this.props.menu.megamenu.map((menuitem, index) = > (
                <div key={index}>
                    <li>{menuitem.name}</li>
                    </div>
                    ))}
            </ul>
        </section>
    );
}
```

**But would like to map all the levels and display like below structure :**

```
<ul>
    <li>Level1.1
    <li>
    <li>Level1.2
        <div className="dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li>A</li>
                <li>B</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>A-one</li>
                <li>b-one</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
<li>
<li>Level1.3
    <div className="dropdown">
        <div className="col">
            <h2>level1.3.1</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>level1.3.1.1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="col">
            <h2>level1.3.2</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>level1.3.1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</li>
<ul>
```

I have tried to explain in details for better understanding, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should write a recursive function to write indeterminate depth hierarchy.

Comment: What is `level1.2.1`? it should be children

Comment: also, your structure looks inconsistent, as sometimes you have keys sometimes you have children, you need to change your structure first.

Comment: @AmerllicA : Do you have any sample / Example for this recursive function ?

Comment: @Justcode : Yes this structure is inconsistent but this is what I am getting from API, only this part of JSON is having different structure.

 `{
                    "name": "level1.2","link": "#","level1.2.1": {
                        "A": [
                            { "name": "A-one",
                                "link": "#"
                            }
                        ],
                        "B": [{"name": "B-one",
                            "link": "#"
                        }],
                    }
                },`

Comment: @Justcode : Would you suggest any other structure ?

Comment: I would suggest `children` instead of `level1.2.1` for all levels

Comment: @Justcode : I am not sure if I would be able to change the structure as of now, but if you see the HTML structure I need is like this where `level1.2.1` is having 2 arrays which also I need to map and display along with the other objects. Please refer this HTML structure for this `<li>Level1.2
                <div className="dropdown">
                <ul>
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>B</li>
                </ul>
                <ul><li>A-one</li>
<li>b-one</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>`

Comment: @Justcode : Do you have sample of mapping this if we change this to children ?

Comment: @H.Husain I can only suggest to have structure like this then only I can guide you something,http://myjson.com/9bbvk

Comment: @Justcode : Ok I will change the structure as you suggested, Can you guide me to create a map function for this to display the HTML ?

Comment: @H.Husain, No, But undoubtedly creating a menu with unknown depth need a recursive function to generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you would change the structure to something like this,

```
{
  "megamenu": [
    {
      "name": "level1.1",
      "link": "#"
    },
    {
      "name": "level1.2",
      "link": "#",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "A-one",
          "link": "#"
        },
        {
          "name": "B-one",
          "link": "#"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "level1.3",
      "link": "#",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "level1.3.1",
          "link": "#",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "level1.3.1.1",
              "link": "#"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "level1.3.1.2",
          "link": "#",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "level1.3.1.2",
              "link": "#"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Which is quite obvious as adding new keys inside child object is a wrong way, now, you need a recursive function which will take care of this which can be something like this

```
  getData = (menu) => {

    return <div>
      <li>{menu.name}</li>
      {(menu.children !== undefined && menu.children.length > 0) && <ul>{

        menu.children.map(data => {
          return this.getData(data);
        })
      }
      </ul>}
    </div>
  }
```

And inside render you can change to this

```
 return (
      <section>
        <ul>
          {data.megamenu.map((menuitem, index) => (
            this.getData(menuitem)
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
```

So, what we did is calling the recursive function `getdata`.

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-treestructure)

Comment: Thanks for creating the demo, but why `menu.children.children` is undefined, I am trying to access this array like this. `console.log (menu.children.children);` but I am getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`

Comment: @H.Husain its is undefined because children is an array not object, you need to access it by menu.children[0].children

Comment: I tried to access with this but the same error, See this is what I am trying to do `return <li className={menu.children. !== undefined && menu.children.length > 0 ? 'nav-item ddfull subnav' : 'nav-item'}>` Need to apply different class if the level1 is having children inside children

So it does not work when i access like this `return <li className={menu.children.children !== undefined && menu.children.children.length > 0 ? 'nav-item ddfull subnav' : 'nav-item'}>`

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Comment: @H.Husain create stackblitz for it and I will take a look

Comment: Please check the sample code here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v9iknk 

only level1.3 should have the following class because it is only having children inside children `nav-item ddfull subnav`

Comment: Did you get chance to have a look at it ?

Comment: @H.Husain not really I will take a look when I get free time